# Who will set the e-mail as read, SMTP server or email client?

Tags: email, imap, jakarta-mail

I am using IMAP Protocol to read e-mails from a SMTP server. I would like to know who changes the email status from unread to read ? Is it done by the SMTP server or by the e-mail client ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMTP stopped being involved when it delivered the message to the IMAP server. Typically, the IMAP server sets a message's flags to `unread` when it first arrives, and removes this flag when you fetch the message.

In theory, a client could keep its own local per-message state independently from the server's, but for read / unread status, this doesn't make much sense. For other metainformation, this may be used as a mechanism for other kinds of message status; for example, Thunderbird's message tags do not appear to be saved on the server.

Incidentally, there is a `peek` option in the IMAP protocol for examining a message without affecting its unread status.